# How to convert a list of dictionaries to a tensorflow dataset?

Tags: python, json, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a `.jsonl` dataset that I am trying to convert into a tensorflow dataset.

Each line of the .jsonl is of the form

```
{"text": "some text", "meta": "irrelevant"}
```

I need to get it into a tensorflow dataset where each element has a key "text" associated with a tf.string value.

It seems like the closest I've gotten is the following

```
import tensorflow as tf

ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset('train_mini.jsonl')

def f(tnsr):
    text = eval(tnsr.numpy())['text']
    return tf.constant(text)
    #return {'text':text}

ds = ds.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(func=f,inp=[x], Tout=tf.string))

ds = tf.data.Dataset({"text": list(ds.as_numpy_iterator())})
```

which throws the following error

```
InvalidArgumentError: ValueError: Error converting unicode string while converting Python sequenc
e to Tensor.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/crytting/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", l
ine 241, in __call__
    return func(device, token, args)

  File "/home/crytting/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", l
ine 130, in __call__
    ret = self._func(*args)

  File "/home/crytting/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py
", line 309, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/crytting/persuasion/json_to_tfds.py", line 7, in f
    return tf.constant(text)

  File "/home/crytting/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op
.py", line 262, in constant
    allow_broadcast=True)

  File "/home/crytting/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op
.py", line 270, in _constant_impl
    t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)

  File "/home/crytting/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op
.py", line 96, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)

ValueError: Error converting unicode string while converting Python sequence to Tensor.


         [[{{node EagerPyFunc}}]]
```

I have tried many many ways of doing this, but nothing has worked. It seems like it shouldn't be this hard, and I'm wondering if I'm missing some really simple way of doing it.

Comment: Use `tf.io.decode_json_example` method to read the Json file then `tf.data.Dataset` library to get Tensorflow dataset. Thanks!

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

now days (02/2024) you can use pandas along side TensorFlow to make it easy.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

# assume data is the data comming from your .jsonl file
# something like reading it with json.load()
df = pf.Dataframe.from_records(data)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df.to_dict(orient='list'))
```

[image]